# How do I get a resources/Resources.xaml from the executing assembly?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ResourceDictionary in resource/Resources.xaml.  However, I don't know ahead of time what the name of the .dll will be.  Is there anyway to generate the uri for the ResourceDictionary on the fly?  Originally, it was loaded using

```
var myResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
var uri = new Uri("/xxx;component/resource/Resources.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
myResourceDictionary.Source = uri;
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
```

where xxx could change to yyy if I include the file in a different Project.

**Update.** By turning the Resource.xaml from a Page to an Embedded Dictionary, I was able to load it using

```
// http://chris.59north.com/post/Storing-application-wide-styles-in-external-files-aka-The-ExternalStyleManager.aspx
Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
foreach (var key in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
{
    if (key.ToLower().EndsWith(".resources.xaml"))
    {
        Stream resource = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(key);
        ResourceDictionary dict = XamlReader.Load(resource) as ResourceDictionary;
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
    }
}
```

But this is a bit unsatisfactory.  Still would be interested to know if there is a way to keep it as a Page and load it.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but keep in mind that `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` can sometimes give the wrong result. A better way would be to use `typeof(classInAssembly).Assembly`

Comment: Good, thanks for the reminder Jan-Peter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to build up the URI based on the current assembly. So using Jan-Peter's tip, an example would be:

```
var myResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
var uriPath = string.Format("/{0};component/resource/Resources.xaml", 
    typeof(classInAssembly).Assembly.GetName().Name);
var uri = new Uri(uriPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
myResourceDictionary.Source = uri;
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
```

but you may need to use the long form:

```
var uriPath = string.Format("pack://application:,,,/{0};component/resource/Resources.xaml", 
    typeof(classInAssembly).Assembly.Name);
```

Comment: BTW, I did not need the long form.

Comment: @tofutim - URIs can be finicky at times, depending on where and how you use them.